# mod_jk help with apache2 tomcat6 and railo3 on ubuntu server 9.04

Tags: tomcat, apache2, ubuntu-9.04, mod-jk, railo

I am trying to setup the coldfusion server railo on tomcat6 and using apache2 to connect to tomcat via mod_jk.
I've gotten everything setup except that i would like to be able to have my railo webapp use the /var/www (my default apache directory) as its home directory since not every file need to be processed by railo. What is the best way to go about this?

[EDIT]
Let me be more clear why i want to be able to use this kind of method. Im planning on having multiple virtual hosts in apache that would all ideally have all of their coldfusion pages served by railo since several of the subdomains would be rarely used (admin, etc) so it seems a waste to have a separate railo app for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Using the context tag to set the docBase to your directory

```
...
<Host ...>
  <Context path="" docBase="/var/www" />
</Host>
```